# Ordenar un vector de estructuras alfabéticamente por el apellido

Tags: c++, ordenamiento

Estoy intentando ordenar alfabéticamente por método Shell un arreglo de estructuras, solamente contiene Nombre, Apellido, Edad e Indice, algo muy básico.

Ahora bien, el método solo ordena cuando el vector es menor a 4, de otra forma no muestra el vector ordenado, aquí dejo el código:

```
struct Estudiante{
    char apellido[20];
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
    int indice;
};
```

Y el método shell:

```
void ordenarEstudiantes(Estudiante *e, int tam){
    int j, k, salto;
    Estudiante aux;

    salto = tam / 2;

    while(salto > 0){
        for(int i = salto; i < tam; i++){
            j = i - salto;

            while(j >= 0){
                k = j + salto;

                if(strcmp(e[j].apellido, e[k].apellido) < 0){
                    j = -1;
                }else{
                    aux = e[j];
                    e[k] = e[j];
                    e[k] = aux;
                }
            }           
        }
        salto = salto / 2;
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Así a bote pronto el error más destacable de tu código es el siguiente:

```
}else{
  aux = e[j];
  e[k] = e[j];
  e[k] = aux;
}
```

Ahí estás intentando hacer un swap de `e[j]` y `e[k]`, es decir, intercambiar sus valores... pero lo estás haciendo mal. Fíjate que `e[k]` lo asignas dos veces seguidas... no tiene buena pinta.

```
}else{
  aux = e[j];
  e[j] = e[k];
  e[k] = aux;
}
```

Y luego, a modo de consejo, intenta que las variables tengan la menor vida posible... En tu caso concreto, `j`, `k` y `aux` tienen una vida excesivamente larga. Acortar la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible ayuda a evitar errores bastante complicados de encontrar.

```
void ordenarEstudiantes(Estudiante *e, int tam){
int salto = tam / 2;

while(salto > 0){
    for(int i = salto; i < tam; i++){
        int j = i - salto;

        while(j >= 0){
            int k = j + salto;

            if(strcmp(e[j].apellido, e[k].apellido) < 0){
                j = -1;
            }else{
                Estudiante aux = e[j];
                e[j] = e[k];
                e[k] = aux;
            }
        }           
    }
    salto /= 2;
}
```

**EDITO:** A instancias de @PaperBirdMaster para mejorar el código

Una alternativa más limpia para intercambiar el valor de dos variables es usar la función `swap`:

```
while(salto > 0){
    for(int i = salto; i < tam; i++){
        int j = i - salto;

        while(j >= 0){
            int k = j + salto;

            if(strcmp(e[j].apellido, e[k].apellido) < 0){
                j = -1;
            }else{
                swap(e[j],e[k]);
            }
        }           
    }
    salto /= 2;
}
```

Otra posible mejora a implementar en tu código es el uso de la clase `string` en vez de recurrir a `char*`. Los strings a la usanza de C presentan muchas deficiencias en C++:

- Hay que estar pendientes de su tamaño todo el rato
- Si se crean en la pila no se puede modificar su tamaño máximo
- Hay que usar funciones externas para modificar su contenido
- Posibilidad de acceder a memoria no válida
- Posibilidad de tener fugas de memoria

La clase `string` se diseñó con la idea de evitar que el programador tuviese que enfrentarse a todos estos problemas constantemente. Además la sobrecarga de operadores que incorpora hace que su uso sea bastante natural:

```
struct Estudiante{
    string apellido;
    string nombre;
    int edad;
    int indice;
};

Estudiante e;
e.nombre = "Juan";
e.apellido = "Perez";
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muy bien visto eferion; ¿puedo sugerirte que comentes el uso de `std::swap` como alternativa al swap manual y la substitución de arrays estáticos de `char` por `std::string`? Lo haría yo mismo pero no creo que pueda aportar nada interesante que no hayas aportado ya.

Comment: Claro, lo edito en seguida. Pensé en ponerlo pero no quería alejarme mucho del código inicial porque tiene toda la pinta de ser un ejercicio de clase y éstos suelen estar limitados en cuanto a llamadas a la STL :)

Comment: sólo tenemos nuestra intuición para determinar que es un ejercicio de clase pues (salvo error u omisión) no me parece que Jesús V. haya comentado que lo sea. Por otro lado, aún siendo un ejercicio académico, conocer más alternativas no hace daño, al contrario: amplía los horizontes del estudiante.

Comment: Por ese motivo te he hecho caso y he ampliado la respuesta. Con tu comentario me ayudaste a despejar las dudas sobre si recargar la respuesta o no

Comment: Aunque sin el añadido la respuesta era ya muy buena, ahora ha quedado una respuesta mejor :) ¡buen trabajo!

Comment: gracias a tí por la colaboración

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Jeje, no pude responder porque tuve que salir de viaje un rato largo, hoy justo acabo de llegar, como dicen, es un ejercicio académico, no he empezado clases aún, y quería adelantar por mi cuenta, muchas gracias y disculpen la tardanza en responder!

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor, cuando la opción existe, es utilizar una buena librería que haga el trabajo por ti.
En este caso ni siquiera hace falta una externa. C++ viene de casa, en versiones modernas, con `std::sort` en `<algorithm>`.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>

struct Estudiante{
    char apellido[20];
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
    int indice;

    bool operator < (const Estudiante& e) const
    {
        return strcmp( apellido, e.apellido ) < 0;
    }
};


void ordenarEstudiantes(Estudiante *e, int tam){
  std::sort( e, e+tam );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Estudiante arregloEjemplo[] = {
        { "Perez", "Juan", 2, 1 },
        { "Lopez", "Super", 23, 2 },
        { "Thatcher", "Margaret", 87, 3},
        { "Pi", "Filemon", 48, 4}
    };
    ordenarEstudiantes( arregloEjemplo,
                        sizeof(arregloEjemplo)/sizeof(*arregloEjemplo) );
    for ( const auto& e : arregloEjemplo )
    {
        std::cout << e.apellido << "," << e.nombre << "," << e.edad <<
                     "," << e.indice << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```